# Select property names based on given string

Tags: c#

I want to avoid duplicated code. At the moment I iterate over certain "options" and then based on the option I calculate a value. The code looks something like this:

```
if (option == "A")
    result = (y[0].A - y[1].A) / (x[0].A - x[1].A);

if (option == "B")
    result = (y[0].B - y[1].B) / (x[0].B - x[1].B);

if (option == "C")
    result = (y[0].C - y[1].C) / (x[0].C - x[1].C);
```

It is doing the same for A,B and C - is there a way to use the string "option" to select the desired property (A,B,C) of x and y?

> x,y is Dictionary<int, class>, and this class has the properties A,B,C which are doubles

Comment: What is the type of `y` and 'x'? And `A`, `B` and `C`?

Comment: x,y is Dictionary<int, class>, and this class has the properties A,B,C which are doubles

Comment: Without any further knowledge, I'd factor out the function first "(a-b/c-d)" , then instead of a string option, I'd make that 3 distinct functions. Anything above that would need either more info and/or bigger redesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that 'option' will always be the same value as the name of the property you can use:

```
PropertyInfo info = typeof(<insert class y here>).GetProperty(option);
PropertyInfo info2 = typeof(<insert class x here>).GetProperty(option);
result = (double)info.GetValue(y[0]) - (double)info.GetValue(y[1]) / (double)info2.GetValue(x[0]) - (double)info2.GetValue(x[1])
```

This code is untested, but should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0), for example:

```
public double DoCalculation(Func<YourClassName, double> property, Foo y0, Foo y1, Foo x0, Foo x1)
{
    // Now we can call the Func on the objects passed in:
    return (property(y0) - property(y1)) / (property(x0) - property(x1));
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
result = DoCalculation(
    f => f.A, //<--- this is how you specify the property to call
    y[0], y[1], x[0], x[1]);
```

The reason I would do it this way over the other methods that use reflection:

1. Reflection is slower (though not so much that you would likely notice in this code)
2. This method has compile-time type safety. If you use reflection, you won't know that the method doesn't exist on the class until runtime.

Comment: You will still need reflection to create lambda expression from the `option` variable. Or you will need a switch case expression that converts the string to lambda expression.

Comment: @Eldar Yes you probably still need the switch, but the point is the calculation is only specified in one place, it's much safer code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection like below :

```cs
public double GetResult(string option) {

    var prop = x[0].GetType().GetProperty(option);

    var y0 = (double)prop.GetValue(y[0]);
    var y1 = (double)prop.GetValue(y[1]);

    var x0 = (double)prop.GetValue(x[0]);
    var x1 = (double)prop.GetValue(x[1]);

    var result = (y0-y1) / (x0-x1);
    return result;
}
```